# Visual Studio 2017 MVC does not contain all source folders

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I have an issue with the new Visual Studio 2017 when starting a new ASP.NET MVC project. Recently I started a course on Udemy:

https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-aspnet-mvc-5-course/learn/v4/content

In this course I obviously try to mimic the teacher as perfectly as possible. However, I bought a new laptop yesterday and installed VS2017 on it (apparently you cannot get VS2015 as easily anymore). I followed the same steps as with VS2015 on my previous laptop, but it seems that the files generated by VS2017 are less than those generated by VS2015. Two of the files I'm missing are:

- Startup.cs
- Models/IdentityModels.cs

And there are several more missing, for instance regarding the Account Managing. The files in VS2017 look like this:

[VS2017 MVC generated files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybuFF.png)

Unfortunately I don't have a snippet of the VS2015 version, since I already reset my old laptop to factory settings.

Are there others with the same issue, or is this standard since VS2017? Right now I can just look at what the teacher does, but later on he will introduce logging in and authentication, at which point I assume I will need that Account Manager .cs file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What kind of authentication model did you choose when creating your VS2017 MVC project?

Comment: @itsme86 The default option is set to 'No Authentication' and I left it like that, just like in the tutorial video.

Comment: With the 2017 templates you should choose Individual User Accounts for authentication. Then the files you want scaffolded will be there.

Comment: @Jasen I just changed it and that did the trick! And I checked back just to see that the instructor also had individual user accounts on, but it was default with him, so I didn't change anything because he didn't. Blunder on my side. Thanks for the reaction.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to itsme86 and Jasen I found the "issue". Just needed to put the authentication model to "Individual user accounts" when creating the project. Stupid error from my side.

Comment: How do I set the Authentication Model in Visual Studio for Mac, there is no option like this initially ?

Comment: Hello, Can you please share something about adding `Authentication Model` to `Individual User Accounts` while creating the project? I'm using `Visual Studio 2019 Community edition` and I do not see any option to enable that after selecting `Authentication Model`